# GWT 2: как сделать общий для нескольких модулей сервлет?

Tags: maven, gwt, servlet, java

Есть некий server-side сервис, который лезет в БД и что-то отдает. Он есть сервлет. Изначально он использовался как server-side для GWT проекта, и успешно взаимодействовал с его клиентской частью (UI).

Теперь возникла необходимость подключить к этому сервису другой GWT модуль, совершенно отдельный UI.

Как это сделать?

Варианты:

1. Вынести код сервиса в отдельный jar и подключать его к сервлетам всех новых GWT модулей. 
   Недостатки: будет 2 одинаковых сервлета, что в общем-то не нужно. Два кэша в Хибернейте например. Непонятная ситуация с многопоточностью: один сервлет к примеру сразу после update будет видеть то, что не видит другой (у второго flusha-то не будет). Можно ли вообще писать в базу с двух разных Хибернейтов?
2. Поднять сервис совершенно независимым сервлетом, и как-то направить UI двух GWT модулей на посторонний сервлет. Это вообще возможно?
   Не очень удачная конфигурация: в серверный модуль все равно придется пихать библиотеки GWT чтобы имплементить `RemoteServiceServlet`. Или даже это должен быть GWT модуль без клиентской части. Непонятно, сработает ли это все.
3. Пусть новые GWT UI модули обращаются к сервлету уже существующего. Для этого надо как-то дать им доступ к его интерфейсам, непонятно как. Надо как-то выдрать интерфейсы из wara существуюшего GWT модуля и добавить их в качестве dependency в новый GWT модуль, чтобы тот создавал из них сервисы через `GWT.create(...)`. Не знаю как это оформить в Mavene.

Что скажете?

Answer (score 1):

Такие проблемы решаются созданием специализированного слоя. На данном этапе у вас грубо говоря 2 слоя:

1. Клиентский слой
2. Server-side слой (собсно сервлет или контроллер)

Воткните между ними еще 1 слойчик, который собсно занимается получением запросов из клиентской части и пересылкой их в контроллер. Можно назвать это разновидностью [паттерна delegate](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

1. Клиентский слой
2. Слой delegate
3. Server-side

В таком разрезе функцией слоя делегата будет "эмулирование" серверного слоя, так что клиентам будет "казаться", что они работают с сервером, хотя функции работы с сервером полностью на себя возьмет слой делегата, которому и делегированы эти полномочия.

Не силен в GWT так что в части механизма реализации ничего не подскажу.

Comment: В данном случае какие были проблемы связываения 1) и 2) в GWT, такие же и остались. 

Вы просто переименовали 2 и добавили к нему новые  функции (невидимые) 1.